# Google Sheet Cells Showing the Wrong Time They Were Last Updated?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Using a checklist on Google Sheets for my staff to use. Every time they complete a task, they check a box in Column A and the time they updated that cell pops up in Column B. Only issue is that, this morning 5/16/ at 9:00am, they're checking off the boxes but its showing up as 5/15 at ~11:50pm? It was working perfectly yesterday so not sure what the issue could be, Column B is protected as well so nobody but me can't edit the times.

This is the Google Scripts code im using at the moment, as well as a picture of part of my Google Sheet for better context. If anybody could help out it would be gladly appreciated.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  // Get the sheet object
  var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  
  // Check if the edited cell is in Column A
  if (e.range.getColumn() == 5) {
    // Get the row number of the edited cell
    var row = e.range.getRow();
    
    // Get the value of the edited cell
    var value = e.value;
    
    // Get the current date and time
    var d = new Date();
    
    // Format the date and time as a string
    var formattedDate = d.toLocaleString();
    
    // Construct the "Last Updated On" string
    var lastUpdatedOn = formattedDate;
    
    // Update the corresponding cell in Column B with the value and date
    sheet.getRange(row, 6).setValue(value + "\n" + lastUpdatedOn);
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have used the function you provided and it worked for me, anyway I have made some changes, and I hope it works for you.

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  var range = e.range;
  var sheet = range.getSheet();
  var column = range.getColumn();
  
  if (column == 5) {
    var row = range.getRow();
    var value = e.value;
    var formattedDate = new Date().toLocaleString();
    var lastUpdatedOn = formattedDate;
    
    sheet.getRange(row, 6).setValue(value + "\n" + lastUpdatedOn);
  }
}
```